# What is the right API to use to remap keys in OSX?

Tags: macos, nstouchbar

I'm looking at Karabiner, the OSX keyboard remapper for Parallels development.  According to [this issue](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner/issues/739) this is best fixed by filing a bug with Apple.

What is the alternative (if any) supported API to create such a functionality?

Answer (score 1):

As [noted](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner/issues/739#issuecomment-561049614) by [pkamb](https://github.com/pkamb) on the github issue that OP linked to (added since he posted), [Apple technote TN2450](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html) documents the proper API:

> The IOKit HID APIs can be used for key remapping. The user will
> provide a dictionary of key remapping that the HID event system will
> apply to the keyboard.
>  Listing 3 : Key Remapping using IOKit HID
> APIs. // compiled with Xcode 8.2.1
>
> ```
> #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
> #import <IOKit/hidsystem/IOHIDEventSystemClient.h>
> #import <IOKit/hidsystem/IOHIDServiceClient.h>
> #import <IOKit/hid/IOHIDUsageTables.h>
>
> int main(int argc, char *argv[])
> {
>     IOHIDEventSystemClientRef system;
>     CFArrayRef services;
>
>     uint64_t aKey = 0x700000004;
>     uint64_t bKey = 0x700000005;
>
>     NSArray *map = @[
>                      @{@kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrcKey:@(aKey),
>                         @kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingDstKey:@(bKey)},
>                      @{@kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrcKey:@(bKey),
>                         @kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingDstKey:@(aKey)},
>                      ];
>
>     system = IOHIDEventSystemClientCreateSimpleClient(kCFAllocatorDefault);
>     services = IOHIDEventSystemClientCopyServices(system);
>     for(CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(services); i++) {
>         IOHIDServiceClientRef service = (IOHIDServiceClientRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(services, i);
>         if(IOHIDServiceClientConformsTo(service, kHIDPage_GenericDesktop, kHIDUsage_GD_Keyboard)) {
>             IOHIDServiceClientSetProperty(service, CFSTR(kIOHIDUserKeyUsageMapKey), (CFArrayRef)map);
>         }
>     }
>
>     CFRelease(services);
>     CFRelease(system);
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

**Example:**
If you are trying to re-map the command / option / control keys on an external USB keyboard, take a look at the `enum`'s defined in `IOHIDUsageTables.h`. For example, a Z-88 keyboard can be remapped to match the key layout on a MacBookPro using this mapping:

```
NSArray *remap = @[
  @{@kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrcKey:@(0x7000000E3),
    @kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingDstKey:@(0x7000000E2)},
  @{@kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrcKey:@(0x7000000E2),
    @kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingDstKey:@(0x7000000E3)},
  @{@kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrcKey:@(0x7000000E6),
    @kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingDstKey:@(0x7000000E7)},
  @{@kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrcKey:@(0x700000065),
    @kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingDstKey:@(0x7000000E6)}
];
```

- LeftGUI (E3) → LeftAlt (E2)
- LeftAlt (E2) → LeftGUI (E3)
- RightAlt (E6) → RightGUI (E7)
- Application (65) → RightAlt (E6)

To undo a mapping, map the same keys back to their original values. Using the above example:

```
NSArray *unmap = @[
  @{@kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrcKey:@(0x7000000E3),
    @kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingDstKey:@(0x7000000E3)},
  @{@kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrcKey:@(0x7000000E2),
    @kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingDstKey:@(0x7000000E2)},
  @{@kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrcKey:@(0x7000000E6),
    @kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingDstKey:@(0x7000000E6)},
  @{@kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrcKey:@(0x700000065),
    @kIOHIDKeyboardModifierMappingDstKey:@(0x700000065)}
];
```

Answer (score -1):

[Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) is solid and versatile despite the sketchy documentation and user interface, excusable for a work in progress.  There are many useful examples, e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62146624/3008405) which required dedicated tools and the Karabiner error log to generate the tricky JSON rules.  Any key can be both a modifier and regular key, run a program, etc., all at once.  Public domain on GitHub.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer to the question of what API one should use for key remapping on macOS.

Comment: Perhaps the best answer is don't re-invent Karabiner now that Karabiner-Elements resolves the issue that led to the question.

Comment: OP specifically asked for an alternative to Karabiner. Granted, it appears that development may be underway again after a ~3 year hiatus, so it might be worth reevaluating Karabiner as an option, but this still does not answer the question.

Comment: Karabiner-Elements is an alternative to Karabiner.