# French keyboard on macOS, altering the behavior of the tilde ~ key

Tags: macos, keyboard, key-bindings, french, karabiner

Like most french users, when I want to go to my terminal home, I have to type

```
cd ~
```

However, the keyboard requires me to press `options + n` and *then* `space` to disambiguate between me trying to do `ñ` or `~` for example.

Is there a way to overload this behavior, as I almost never want to use the tilde symbol the way spanish people does ?

[Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) looked promising but it won't let you define custom mapping. It requires you to chose between a set of predefined ones, online.

Comment: Karabiner lets you roll your own, see my example below.

Answer (score 2):

[Ukelele](http://software.sil.org/ukelele) can create a keyboard variation where tilde <kbd>~</kbd> is not a dead key, probably your best bet if you can get it to launch without hanging.  You can always type **ñ** by holding down the <kbd>n</kbd> key for a second.  [Karabiner-Elements](https://Karabiner-Elements.pqrs.org), AppleScript, etc. can only type what your keyboard supports, e.g., these bash commands with Karabiner:

```
cat > ~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications/azerty-tilde.json <<.
{"title": "AZERTY tilde",
 "rules": [
   {"description": "AZERTY tilde emits space after dead key ~ (option-n) for French keyboard.
Bug: auto-repeat gets only spaces after the initial tilde.",
    "manipulators": [
      {"type": "basic",
       "from": {"key_code": "n", "modifiers": {"mandatory": ["option"]}},
       "to": [{"key_code": "n", "modifiers": ["option"]},
              {"key_code": "spacebar"}]}]}]}
.
```

Now the "AZERTY tilde" rule is installed.

```
Open -a Karabiner-Elements
```

Pick this **Karabiner-Elements** menu sequence to enable the "AZERTY tilde" rule:

*Window > Karabiner-Elements Preferences > Complex Modifications > Rules > Add Rule*

In the ***Add rule*** window, find "AZERTY tilde" on the left and use the corresponding  <kbd>⊕ Enable</kbd>  button on the right.
Now every dead-key tilde is followed by a space.  The "AZERTY tilde"  <kbd>⊕ Remove</kbd>  button disables it.
Tested in Emacs with ns-option-modifier set to none, FireFox, iTerm and Terminal.

Comment: THANNNNNNKKS!!!!!!!!